# Remove all dots but the first in a character string

Tags: regex, r

I want to replace all but first consecutive dots. Here is an example of what I want:

```
> names.orig <- c("test & best", "test & worse &&&&  ? do")
> names <- make.names(names.orig)
> names
[1] "test...best"             "test...worse.........do"
> 
> # But I want this instead:
> # [1] "test.best"             "test.worse.do"
> 
> # Desperatley tried:
> gsub("\\.{2, }", "", names)
[1] "testbest"    "testworsedo"
> gsub("\\G((?!^).*?|[^\\.]*\\.*?)\\.", "", names)
Error in gsub("\\G((?!^).*?|[^\\.]*\\.*?)\\.", "", names) : 
  invalid regular expression '\G((?!^).*?|[^\.]*\.*?)\.', reason 'Invalid regexp'
> # etc.
> 
> # The only thing that works for me is this
> unlist(lapply(strsplit(names, "\\."), function(x) paste(x[x != ""], collapse=".")))
[1] "test.best"     "test.worse.do"
> 
> # But, really, what is the right regex in combination with what?
```

How to solve this with regex?

Comment: its simple you can replace .+ to .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the `""` with `"."` in your first regex:

```
R> nms <- make.names(c("test & best", "test & worse &&&&  ? do"))
R> gsub("\\.{2, }", ".", nms)
[1] "test.best"     "test.worse.do"
```

This also works.  Basically, you're replacing all dots and consecutive dots with a single dot.

```
R> gsub("\\.+", ".", nms)
[1] "test.best"     "test.worse.do"
```

Comment: Joshua thanks. I knew it was so obvious I just could not see it... :)